# Inline CSS Not Centering <div>

Tags: css, html, center

I have read other questions on stackoverflow about centering and have used this technique before.

I tried using:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; position: absolute; margin: 300px auto 0px auto;">
content in here
</div>
```

This did not center the div. What have I done wrong? I feel like I have used this code before, but it will not work this time. I tried making a new html file, and I tried it in case I had done something wrong on this particular page. It was flawed as well. How is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `position: absolute`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZSEE/).

BTW, it as nothing to do with the fact the styles are inline.

Answer (score 0):

The auto margin trick doesn't work for elements that have absolute positioning. Try the following instead:

```
width: 1000px;
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -500px;
```

This works by centring the LHS of the element using `left: 50%` then centering the element by using a negative margin of exactly half it's width.

Comment: Do people use this often? Is it valid and efficient?

Comment: This is a valid solution for centre aligning a absolutely positioned element. The same technique works for vertical alignment. [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=center+align+absolute+div)